# dictionary key and values to CSV

Tags: python, dictionary, export-to-csv

I have a dictionary:

```
{1: ['company_name1', 'address1, number1 St Street, London', '+44 20 0000 5111', 'emailname@company1'], 2: ['company_name2', 'address2, number2 St Street, London', '+44 20 0200 5111', 'emailname@company2.com'],
```

and I would like to get in a CSV file the following:
*each | is a column

```
'ID'|'NAME'| 'ADDRESS'| 'PHONE'| 'EMAIL' |(headers in each column)

1| company_name1| address1 number1 St Street London| +44 20 0000 5111 | emailname@company1

2| company_name2| address2 number2 St Street London| +44 20 0200 5111 | emailname@company2.com
```

I've tried:

```
csv_columns = ['ID','NAME', 'ADDRESS', 'PHONE', 'EMAIL']
    with open('some_name.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvfile:

    my_writer = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter='\t', quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
    for key, val in my_dict.items():
        my_writer.writerow([key] + val)
```

but it mixes all the data in cells like:

```
1| company_name1address1 number1 St Street London| +44 20 0000 5111 emailname@company1

2| company_name2| address2 number2 St Street London +44 20 0200 5111 emailname@company2.com
```

What can I do?  and how I can add the headers?

Comment: Where would the headers come from?

Comment: What version of Python are you using?

Comment: If you want `|` to separate columns, why did you specify the delimiter to be `\t`?

Comment: headers are coming from: csv_columns = ['ID','NAME', 'PHONE', 'ADDRESS', 'EMAIL']

Comment: From a variable you didn't bother to mention: got it.

Comment: and I using Python 3.9.0. I don't want | to separate columns, imagine that | is the CSV format of a new cell.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this:

```
my_dict = {1: ['company_name1', 'address1, number1 St Street, London', '+44 20 0000 5111', 'emailname@company1'], 
            2: ['company_name2', 'address2, number2 St Street, London', '+44 20 0200 5111', 'emailname@company2.com']}

with open('some_name.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
    my_writer = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter='\t', quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
    for key, val in my_dict.items():
        my_writer.writerow([key, val[0], val[1], val[2], val[3]])
```

Comment: I don't know why is still random mixing key and values in the same cell.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't the fastest way to do it but it might teach you some new tricks:

```py
import csv

# my usual csv function
def write_csv(data: dict, path: str):
    with open(path, 'w') as file:
        # get all the keys
        fieldnames = set().union(*data)
        writer = csv.DictWriter(file,
                                fieldnames=fieldnames,
                                lineterminator='\n')
        writer.writeheader()
        writer.writerows(data)


headers = ['id', 'name', 'address', 'phone', 'email']

data = {
    1: [
        'company_name1',
        'address1, number1 St Street, London',
        '+44 20 0000 5111',
        'emailname@company1.com'
    ],
    2: [
        'company_name2',
        'address2, number2 St Street, London',
        '+44 20 0200 5111',
        'emailname@company2.com'
    ],
 }

# crazy cool comprehension to transform the data shape
new_data = [{header: value
             for header, value in zip(headers, [key, *values])}
            for key, values in data.items()]

write_csv(new_data, './data.csv')
```

Output csv:

```
name,address,id,email,phone
company_name1,"address1, number1 St Street, London",1,emailname@company1.com,+44 20 0000 5111
company_name2,"address2, number2 St Street, London",2,emailname@company2.com,+44 20 0200 5111
```

Pretty print of the transformed dict:

```py
[{'address': 'address1, number1 St Street, London',
  'email': 'emailname@company1.com',
  'id': 1,
  'name': 'company_name1',
  'phone': '+44 20 0000 5111'},
 {'address': 'address2, number2 St Street, London',
  'email': 'emailname@company2.com',
  'id': 2,
  'name': 'company_name2',
  'phone': '+44 20 0200 5111'}]
```

Comment: @Piwero great to know it worked! One thig to keep in mind, if your data is HUGE, this may not be the most efficient way to do this.